# Rest Service securization using JWT

Tags: jax-rs, jwt

I am trying to implement a token-based authentication on my web service.
I followed this tutorial : [Tutoriel](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2016/10/03/securing-jax-rs-endpoints-with-jwt/)

First, when I get a token from the web service and I test it here : [Website to test JWT Token](https://jwt.io/#debugger) I got a the message : invalid signature

And when I tried to identify my token from my web service (between my application and the ws), this function throws an exception :

```
Unable to read JSON value: XXXX (some data...)
```

Here the code to generate a token :

```
private String issueToken(String username) {
    SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(username)
            .setIssuer(context.getAbsolutePath().toString())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(60L).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
            .compact();
    return jwtToken;
}
```

And here the code to check if the sent token is valid :

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
    String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
    String token = "";

    if(authorizationHeader != null)
        token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

    try {
        // Validate the token
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println(key);
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are re-generating your secret key each time. with a HS algo, you need to use a symmetric key (ie one that is shared with other parties to verify the tokens). Try it with the same key

Comment: I just looked at the tutorial you linked to, that should work. If you are using the SimpleKeyGenerator, then the symmetric key is "simplekey". You can actually put this into jwt.io to confirm your token is valid - in the "verify signature" box on the bottom right.

Comment: @stringy05 For the KeyGenerator, it is instantiated with : 
this.keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSha512");

Comment: can you show your token? Without it's impossible to tell the reason for `Unable to read JSON value: XXXX (some data...)`

Comment: @jps eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvayIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9kZXZpY2VTZXJ2aWNlL2FwaS9hZG1pbi9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlhdCI6MTUzMDI1NjY2MywiZXhwIjoxNTMwMjY3NDYzfQ.pBntnXwy-Rh0L2zBi5QAkmd_FFXLyoA6eO6YkZj1R3AtrPO9rHyxGIFjTjzGaOQ-3R9meywFqRLL_bULdQzoYg

Comment: looks normal. Does it look the same when printed in the line `System.out.println(token);` in your `filter`function? `Jwts.parser()...` throws the exception?

Comment: Yes you're right the key is not the same. I think I now why. I changed the code tutorial and I removed the @Injected annotation from the "keyGenerator" attributes because there was an error : "Unsatisfied dependency : ..."

Comment: Token created : eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvayIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9kZXZpY2VTZXJ2aWNlL2FwaS9hZG1pbi9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlhdCI6MTUzMDI1NzI2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwMjY4MDYwfQ.FGVzy8LFkeNJuL4q0Z8cnJ6MeakHjaAeOjilrBV8pb03CMleBhGF7h4E-yxDqGWNV6_kJfa84jWbGxAlwaCGaA
___________________________

Token comparison : ciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvayIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9kZXZpY2VTZXJ2aWNlL2FwaS9hZG1pbi9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlhdCI6MTUzMDI1NzI2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwMjY4MDYwfQ.FGVzy8LFkeNJuL4q0Z8cnJ6MeakHjaAeOjilrBV8pb03CMleBhGF7h4E-yxDqGWNV6_kJfa84jWbGxAlwaCGaA

Comment: so your line "Token comparison" is the output from `filter`, right?! Then it's missing the first 6 characters, which explains the excpetion you get. The 6 characters get probably deleted in `token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();` . I guess you didn't add the word 'Bearer' to the request and now, instead of deleting 'Bearer' it deletes the first 6 characters of the token .

Comment: Thanks, the mistake came from that. Now I just have an other error : JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted. 

The keys are the same now, so the token should be validated

Comment: if created and received are token are really identical and also the key is the same (check if there are any leading or trailing spaces in the strings) then it should work. If not, I have no idea.

Comment: the first token verifies with the secret 'simplekey', perhaps update the question with both tokens and the code that is getting the SecretKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, thanks to @jps :

"so your line "Token comparison" is the output from filter, right?! Then it's missing the first 6 characters, which explains the excpetion you get. The 6 characters get probably deleted in token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim(); . I guess you didn't add the word 'Bearer' to the request and now, instead of deleting 'Bearer' it deletes the first 6 characters of the token"